# AWS API Tools vs AWS CLI: Is there a reason to use one instead of the other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Amazon Web Services has two different command line interfaces for managing their services without using a web browser: The [EC2 Command Line Interface Tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/command-reference.html) and the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It appears that most of the functionality is available in both families.

For new users and applications, is there any reason to use the legacy `ec2-*` style commands, rather than the `aws ec2 *` commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EC2 command line interface is an older version that just supports the EC2 service, one of many services on AWS. You will want to use the AWS command line interface which supports all AWS services.

Comment: Because customers tend to get upset when you tell them they suddenly have to rewrite all their scripts.  Also, when chaining calls together, or manipulating results, sometimes it's simpler to write in a scripting language (python boto, ruby aws-sdk), so don't forget that route.